# Copy Keyframe from a model A to a model B (that already drives model B)

Tags: animation

to make it short, I'm using rokoko plugin to retarget animation from a model -A- (mixamo skeleton with rokoko Mocap Data) to a model -B- (Genesis8).

It works fine. But, blender (or plugin) creates me a intermediate skeleton that actualy drives my model -B-. Animation is there, my character moves right, but there are no keyframe in it.

There are in model -A- (originaly), the sames in model intermediate (let's say -A"-) but not in my model -B-. I can delete model -A- but not model -A"-.

I need to copy keyframes in my model and delete the other two to be able to clean up my motion, especially because i'm using this plugin to clean motion (https://blendermarket.com/products/animation-layers).

I'm quite desperate because i've tried so much ways to do that and never succed. Below are some tries I've made.

- simple copy/paste keyframes from -A- and/or -A"- to -B-
- Baking animation of -B-
- Copy curves from -A"- and paste (after creating location/rotation/scale for everybones) in -B-

I thought it could be "easy" to just get my keyframes back in my model which already follow them nicely.

I do hope to found someone to help me. I've bought a 5K rokoko suit and feel disapointed not able to use it properly. I can make free custom mocap for thoses who can unlock me.

Thanks <3

[image: example below :]

Comment: Looks like you baked  B in object mode (and the object stays still), while you should bake its poses in pose mode, visual keying. I can be more precise if you upload the file (even a simplified version of it), because I have to analyze how the Rokoko plug-in controls the two armatures. Btw I'm interested in collaborating with someone using Rokoko suit.

Comment: Yep I had another advice like this one on discord few mintures ago, I will try !
Sure thing, add me on discord Chek#3753 and say potato, I will know it's you :)